# How to classify connected clients in socket programming

Tags: sockets, tcp

i'm new to socket programming. I'm really stuck in this.

My question is:

For example we have one server file named server.php that all clients connect to this file throw a tcp connection and specified port

```
var wsUri = "ws://localhost:8080/server.php";
websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
```

Consider that 1000 clients are connected to this file. When server.php sends any data to clients, all 1000 people will receive data.

Now I want to classify connected clients as groups (Like chatrooms). I mean server should send data just to one group (For example 20 members) and not to send data to others.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: How did you achieve the server sending to all 1000 clients? It's just a subset of that.

Comment: 1000 is just an example of clients that are connected to the server. It means all clients.